# @Media query (min-width) CSS is not applying to certain resolutions

Tags: css, wordpress

*(Duplicate as my last question lost traction, cleaned up some un-needed info and added additional relevant info)*

I've been tasked with developing a Wordpress site for and have been fiddling with CSS a bit. I'm now having issues with @media queries

I only need to develop the site for 3 resolutions (Company standards). I don't understand how auto-scaling works in websites, so I've decided to hardcode elements for each of 3 specific resolutions (1920x1080, 1440x900, 1024x768).

In this case, Its for a sidebar (Other elements aren't working either). The position changes I've been making (right: ##px) are not applying to the 1440x900 users, but are instead overwriting the 1024x768 users changes.

*Here's the code:*

**1024x768 Users**

```
 @media (min-width : 768px){
    .sidebar{
        right: 115px;
    }
 }
```

**1440x900 Users**

```
 @media (min-width : 900px){
    .sidebar{
        right: 555px;
    }
 }
```

**1920x1080 Users**

```
 @media (min-width : 1080px){
    .sidebar{
        right: 155px;
    }
 }
```

(Imgur link with more pictures and information: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDIqq.jpg)

Comment: Can you more clearly tell us what is wrong and what happens at the various resolutions?

Comment: Please set reverse order of media Query like: higher one was first then lower and then lowest

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen please refer to the imgur link for an album of what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging, I found that that the 1440x900 resolution was actually receiving changes from the 1920x1080 section.

not 100% sure why that is and I don't have a work around other than just developing for both sizes at once.

just posting this if others have this question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You are applying media query to the height of the desired resolution, not the width. 
For example, for resolution `1920x1080` you wrote:

```
@media (min-width : 1080px){
        .sidebar{
            right: 155px;
    }
}
```

But it should be:

```
@media (min-width: 1920px) {
        .sidebar {
            right: 155px;
    }
}
```

Anyway, because it's a cascade stylesheet, the last media query will overwrite the previous ones.

Comment: `min-width: 1920px` means if the device's width be _greater than or equal to_ 1920px then apply the rule.  Your suggested change is very different than what the OP had.